# How can I add particular symbol in all line end?

Tags: java, file

I had wrote a 500 query in config file. I need each line end '\' symbol. I am to change line by line add '\' symbol. So I take time too much. If any possible way to add all line end with '\' symbol with in few second.........  like regex

note : using IDE intellij

Thanks

before add '\' symbol

```
snowflake.query.hcp_master_data = SELECT MAST.HCO_HCE_ID, XREF_HCO_HCE_ID, ACTV_STAT_CD, 
ADDR, TELEPHN_NBR, FAX_NBR, WEB_URL_ID, 
OWNR_STAT_DESC, PROFIT_STAT_DESC, 
CORP_PAR_HCE_ID, CORP_PAR_NM, 
OWNR_SUB_HCE_ID, OWNR_SUB_NM, 
GPO_PHARML_HCE_ID, GPO_PHARML_NM, 
GPO_MED_SURGCL_HCE_ID, GPO_MED_SURGCL_NM, 
NPI, DDD, CMS 
FROM
```

After add '\' symbol

```
snowflake.query.hcp_master_data = SELECT MAST.HCO_HCE_ID, XREF_HCO_HCE_ID, ACTV_STAT_CD, \
ADDR, TELEPHN_NBR, FAX_NBR, WEB_URL_ID, \
OWNR_STAT_DESC, PROFIT_STAT_DESC, \
CORP_PAR_HCE_ID, CORP_PAR_NM, \
OWNR_SUB_HCE_ID, OWNR_SUB_NM, \
GPO_PHARML_HCE_ID, GPO_PHARML_NM, \
GPO_MED_SURGCL_HCE_ID, GPO_MED_SURGCL_NM, \
NPI, DDD, CMS \
FROM \
```

Comment: You can improve your question by adding code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

replace all

search \n , replace with \\n, remember to open the regex button
[image]

Comment: can i possible only 100 line add '\' symbol

Comment: you can select the lines you want to replace. I use Ctrl + A to select all.

Comment: which space? provide an example?

Comment: line -> ADDR, TELEPHN_NBR, FAX_NBR, WEB_URL_ID,
with '\' ->  ADDR, TELEPHN_NBR, FAX_NBR, WEB_URL_ID, \
now need is -> ADDR, TELEPHN_NBR, FAX_NBR, WEB_URL_ID, (space) then '\'

line end -> space ->  '\'

Comment: just change \\\n to `space + \\\n'

Comment: @ PatrickChen  Now my code work fine.... Thanks for your valuable time